# How to interpret the iptable rule specified in the description?

Tags: iptables, ansible

I am new to iptables and trying to learn the same. What does --set in this iptable rule mean?

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -M recent --name ssh -p tcp --dport 22 --set
```

Can someone explain this iptable rule to me? I am trying to learn iptables and how to configure it using ansible? So, I am not sure how to translate the above iptable rule to ansible.

Comment: Did you already check the manual and need an explanation, or didn't you check the manual? Additionally, the phrase "translate the above iptable rule to ansible" suggests that you don't know what iptable or ansible is, or you should explain better what you want to do.

Comment: Yes i did check the man page of iptables. But I couldn't understand --set option. Ansilbe has the iptables module and I was looking to know what would --set translate to in ansible. Or, know what --set does in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The match extension recent, selected with `-M recent`, has the options

> --name name
>   Specify the list to use for the commands.

and

> --set
>   This will add the source address of the packet to the list.

This in itself will do nothing. It is used in together with another rule that references the same list specified by `--name`. Thiscan be `--rcheck` or `--update`.

> `--rcheck`
>   Check if the source address of the packet is currently in the list.

So there must be another rule somewhere that references `--name ssh`.

---

Ansible is a tool to automatically distribute settings, usually to many targets. It will happily distribute them without caring for the meaning.

You on the other hand should not distribute settings if you don't know what they do.